# Installing asus USB-AC68 wi-fi adapter on ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS step by step for a noob

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, asus

Can someone can help me do this, I have found some old answers here but they both don't work , and I tried to install the drivers from offical asus site with drivers for Linux, but I'm not quite sure how to execute them, can someone please help me out...

```
mateusz@mateusz-ThinkPad-E470:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58db Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:c024 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0b05:1853 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

mateusz@mateusz-ThinkPad-E470:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:b8:e8:6b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:b000(size=256) memory:f2000000-f200ffff
```

Comment: It will be necessary to get some details about your USB adapter first, as they don’t all use the same hardware. Can you connect the adapter to your computer, open Terminal, type `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lshw -c network`, then [edit] your question to include the output of the commands? This will make it more likely that you receive a complete answer 

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it for myself. ASUS USB-AC68 driver successfully installed with this, https://github.com/morrownr/8814au

Comment: This worked like a charm, basically install the dependencies and run the install script, very easy, don't let the huge guide confuse you!

Answer (score 1):

Asus provides a driver package with step by step instructions for installing on Linux at
https://www.asus.com/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-AC68/HelpDesk_Download/.
If those don't work for you, your best bet would be to contact Asus support or the vendor who sold you that device as Ubuntu compatible.

Alternatively, update your question with specific information at which step of those instructions you are encountering a problem and how the problem manifests itself. Be sure to include the exact wording of any error message you get.

Comment: This did not work for me I recommend checking out @Fishman99314 answer, https://askubuntu.com/a/1432682/1078877

Comment: "Did not work" is not a helpful problem description. But this answer is two years old anyway.